# Convert .p12 to .pem for registration in AWS SNS using Scala or Java

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm trying to get my mobile app registered in SNS. Amazon API requires APNS certificate in .pem format and the password for it. I'm receiving binary of the certificate in p12 format. How can I convert it in proper way? Or do I actually need to convert it?

That's what I've got so far:

```
/**
 * @param principal For APNS, is certificate in .pem format.
 * @param credential For APNS, is private key.
 * @param platform APNS of FCM
 * @param appName the application name  
 */
def registerApp(principal: String, credential: String, platform: String, appName: String): String = {

val attributes = Map("PlatformPrincipal" -> principal, "PlatformCredential" -> credential)
val map = mapAsJavaMap(attributes.asInstanceOf[util.Map[String, String]])

val request = new CreatePlatformApplicationRequest()
  .withPlatform(platform)
  .withName(appName)
  .withAttributes(map)

amazonSNSClient.createPlatformApplicationAsync(request).get().getPlatformApplicationArn
```

I've done some research but was not able to find something beautifully simple. I'm not able to use console `keytool` also.

What I basically need is something implementing this

```
openssl pkcs12 -in myFile.p12 -out myFile.pem -nodes
```

in Scala of Java but using input binary.

Comment: Should I tag ios as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround I found to convert p12's byte array to pem and get PlatformPrincipal and PlatformCredential for registration:

```
def registerApnsApp(p12cert: Array[Byte], password: String, appName: String): Future[String] = {
  val p12 = fromP12(new ByteArrayInputStream(p12cert), password).get
  val attributes = Map("PlatformPrincipal" -> fromPem(p12.certificate), "PlatformCredential" -> fromPem(p12.privateKey))
  val attributesMap = mapAsJavaMap(attributes)

  val request = new CreatePlatformApplicationRequest()
    .withPlatform("APNS")
    .withName(appName)
    .withAttributes(attributesMap) 

    Future(amazonSnsClient.createPlatformApplicationAsync(request).get().getPlatformApplicationArn)
  }
```

To get the certificate which is used as PlatformPrincipal in SNS and the key for PlatformPrincipal.

```
 def fromP12(stream: InputStream, password: String): Option[Pkcs12] = {
   val pkcs12 = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", new BouncyCastleProvider())
   pkcs12.load(stream, password.toCharArray)
   while(pkcs12.aliases().hasMoreElements) {
     val alias = pkcs12.aliases().nextElement()
     if (pkcs12.isKeyEntry(alias)) {
       val certificate = pkcs12.getCertificate(alias)
       val privateKey = pkcs12.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray).asInstanceOf[PrivateKey]
       if (privateKey != null && certificate != null) {
        Option(new Pkcs12(certificate, privateKey, alias))
       }
     }
   }
   None
  }
}

def fromPem(obj: Object): String = {
  val out = new StringWriter
  val pem = new PEMWriter(out)
  pem.writeObject(obj)
  pem.close()
  out.getBuffer.toString
}
```

Refactoring/prettifying is needed but hope this will help someone to convert p12 properly and get APNS app registered.

Imports were used:

```
import java.io.{InputStream, StringWriter}
import java.security.{KeyStore, PrivateKey}
import java.security.cert.Certificate

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMWriter
```

Answer (score 2):

(Possible alternative answer)

You don't need Bouncycastle to read PKCS12, basic Java crypto does that. Bouncycastle does provide complete, and (mostly) convenient, PEM functions, which basic Java does not, but the specific ones you need here are not hard to synthesize:

```
static void SO57695413PKCS12ToPEM (String[] args) throws Exception {
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12"); 
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(args[0]), args[1].toCharArray());
    // should close but I'm being lazy here
    PrivateKey pkey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(args[2], args[1].toCharArray());
    Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate(args[2]);
    // or loop over/look at aliases if desired
    System.out.print("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n"
            + Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(pkey.getEncoded())
            + "\r\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n");
    System.out.print("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n"
            + Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(cert.getEncoded())
            + "\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\r\n");
    // or put in a String etc as desired
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Dave. I do need PEM functions as well, to get certificate as string in pem format.

Comment: The code I showed _is_ the two (specific, and simple) PEM-writer functions you need. It doesn't handle all the other cases Bouncy does, but you don't need those other cases.

Comment: I got it. Can I get all the decription, alias etc from Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(cert.getEncoded()) of it just the certificate itself?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're (now) asking. cert.getEncoded() is the binary or 'DER' encoding of the certificate, and the base64 encoding of that with linebreaks plus the BEGIN and END lines, is the PEM encoding. If you mean 'description' a certificate doesn't contain anything called that although there are several things it might or might not contain that couild be considered descriptive. If you mean 'decryption' there is nothing encrypted, or decryptable, in a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak to SNS or if you don't need to convert it, but as far as converting it, I think the best way is to use OpenSSL. See https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html